# What happened to Widereøe flight WF0597?

Tags: landing, circling-approach

WF0597 was a scheduled flight from Bergen Airport Flesland (ENBR) to Kristiansand Kjevik (ENCN). The Embraer E190-E2 immediately started circling Flesland and continued for about 1 hour and 40 minutes, before making a stop at Flesland.

What could have happened to this flight such that it would behave as it did?

- The aircraft never changed its squawk, indicating that it did not file an emergency.
- Multiple aircraft landed while WF0597 was circling, including an E190-E2 also operated by Widerøe, indicating that nothing was wrong with systems/runway at Flesland.

A pilot friend suggested landing rounds, but this means that the flight was cancelled at some point, even though the websites of Widerøe and Flesland says it had departed as scheduled.

Is this normal? If not, any theories as to what might have happened?

[image: screenshot of the flightradar24 app showing WF9840 (WF0597) after landing]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the path for flight [WF9480](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/wf9480). Flightradar24 shows 2 occurrences of such flight one on the 5th August and one on the 6th August, both are training flights for landing practice. From your screenshot, you were looking at the 6th August flight.

[image]

All occurrences of [WF597](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/wf597) show an aircraft regularly departing Bergen and landing in Kristiansand. All have been operated by a Dash-8, none by an Embraer.

[image]

You have probably mixed up two aircraft that were close in the air.